# Delay in getting started - SharePoint designer 2013 manual workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created a simple SharePoint designer workflow and configured it to be manually started. But when the workflow is started it gets stuck in start page for 5 mins before getting started. The version of SharePoint is SharePoint 2013 foundation. In standard version it shows working on it page and then starts the workflow. Is there a way to start the workflow immediately?

Thanks in advance.